# Video file download over SSL is 10 times slower on my Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, ssl

When loading a video files over SSL, speed is 10 times slower than if not using SSL. I am using Tomcat 6 on Windows 7. What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be popular, or what you want to hear, but especially as you mention encryption: Stay on top of the current technology. Tomcat 6 requires Java 5, and both are long outdated. You might not be running on Java 5 any more, but you don't state the JRE version. You're running Tomcat 6 though, which [has seen its end of life in 2016](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html).

Once you have updated: Measure. Try alternatives. There are [multiple ways to set up Tomcat with TLS](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File), and you can also offload TLS connections to an Apache httpd. Compare them all, then decide what measures to take. But start by ruling out outdated components. The cryptography world develops fast, and you want the latest fixes and algorithms. Typically the current algorithms are faster *and* more secure.